# NetBeans - Splash Screen?

Tags: java, netbeans, splash-screen

In File >> Project Properties >> Application dialog I see a text field labeled Splash Screen that allows you to specify a path to an image that can will be used as the splash screen. So I set an image but it does not work. When I run the project, it does not appear?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do it, you can see in more detail in [How to Create a Splash Screen (The Java Tutorials > Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing > Using Other Swing Features)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html)

- Using `java -splash:<file name> <class name>`
- Using `Main-Class: <class name>` and `SplashScreen-Image: <image name>` in the `manifest.mf` file

In particular for NetBeans, you can see the following tutorial: [Splash Screen Beginner Tutorial - NetBeans Wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Splash_Screen_Beginner_Tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that only works with a Web Start project. It would put the path to the splash screen in the .jnlp file and then Java will show that image when executing the Web Start application.

Comment: So it is not for a desktop application?